# What does this notation mean for the piano?

Tags: piano, notation

I saw this in Chopin's Op.25 No.12 etude and was bemused. On the next line, the asterisk reappears on its own. What is this called and what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two unrelated things going on here, and I'm not sure which you're asking about.

The small bit of staff with the tiny notes on it is called an **[ossia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossia)**. It goes with the staff *below* it, and gives you an alternative way to play that passage. In this case, the difference looks to be the location of the accented notes (marked with the > symbol), although I can't see enough of the passage to tell if there are any other differences. (Note: I do not know the meaning of the notation "FA:" before the ossia.)

You also reference the "asterisk" symbol. However, this goes with the staff *above* it, and is a [pedal release marking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_musical_symbols#Pedal_marks). You can see that it is followed by a cursive "P" at the beginning of the next measure, which indicates where the sustain pedal should be depressed. It is then held until the next asterisk.

Comment: Oh, of course it's a pedal release mark. I would have known that if I saw it on its own; I thought it was part of the ossia in this context. Thanks.

Comment: You could have provided fuller information. Which edition is this? Which bar number (or "bottom of 1st page"). I guess the only difference is the different accent positioning; probably "FA" is the name of a particular edition, and this ought to be mentioned in a note somewhere. I have the Cortot edition, and in a different place (bars 76 and 78) he gives the same possibility with extra accent marks in parenthesis, but no comment explaining this. To a certain extent, you give your own interpretation...